# How can I call method from all elements in list array (linq list) C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a list:

```cs
private List<OutlinedObject> allObjects = new List<OutlinedObject>();
```

that contains elements with a public method

```cs
Pulse(string a, int b) {}
```

and I want to call methods from all elements in array not iteratively. I think it should be like this, but it doesn't work:

```cs
allObjects.Pulse("prop", 10);
```

Can I do this in C#?
Is it possible to do this without using delegates?

Comment: Do you wanna call them all at the same time?

Comment: @Andre.Santarosa Yes (if it possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can use [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-5.0) (which actually just iterates the collection executing corresponding action sequentially):

```
allObjects.ForEach(i => i.Pulse("prop", 10));
```

If you want to run them in parallel you can use `AsParallel` (use [`WithDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.withdegreeofparallelism?view=net-5.0) to control number of parallel executions):

```
allObjects.AsParallel().ForAll(i => i.Pulse("prop", 10))
```